# Python Maze Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to solve a maze which is given through a text file with python. The problem I am running into is that when I run though the solver which uses recursion it prints ever possible route but doesn't change the character after finding a dead end.

```
---------------------
|*************|*|***|
|-+-+-+*+-+-+*+*+*+-|
|***|***|***|*|*****|
|*+-+-+*+*+-+-+-+*+*|
|*******|*|*|*****|*|
|-+-+*+*+*+*+-+*+-+-|
|*****|*************|
|-+*+-+-+-+-+-+*+-+*|
|*****|*********|***|
---------------------
```

What I am trying to get it to look like:

```
---------------------
|!!!!!!!!!!!!!|!|***|
|-+-+-+!+-+-+!+!+*+-|
|!!!|!!!|!!!|!|!!*!!|
|!+-+-+!+!+-+-+-+*+!|
|!!!!***|!|!|!!***|!|
|-+-+*+*+!+!+-+*+-+-|
|!!***|*********!!!!|
|-+*+-+-+-+-+-+!+-+!|
|***!!|!!!!!!!!!|!!!|
---------------------
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
def solver(self,r,c):
    if r == (self.endpoint[0]*2) and c == (self.endpoint[1]*2):
        return True
    if self.reverselist[r][c] != ' ':
        return False

    self.setStar(r,c)
    if self.solver(r-1,c):
        self.setExplan(r,c)
        return True
    if self.solver(r,c+1):
        self.setExplan(r,c)
        return True
    if self.solver(r,c-1):
        self.setExplan(r,c)
        return True 
    if self.solver(r+1,c):
        self.setExplan(r,c)
        return True


    return False
```

Edit:
Sorry for providing so little and making it confusing  I will try to provide more to clear things up.

So for this program I am provided a file which contains to three lines at the top. The first line is the size of the board(ex. 10 20), the second line is the starting point(ex.1 1) and the third line contains the ending point(ex.10 20). After these three lines it contains a empty maze using -,+,| as the walls.

This what I call in a seperate function to run everything

```
def main():
    file_choice = input('Enter files name: ')
    lines = open_file('maze510') #change back after !!!!!
    mymaze = Maze(lines)
    start = mymaze.getStart(lines)
    end = mymaze.getEnd(lines)
    mymaze.solver(start[0],start[1])
    mymaze.displaymaze()
```

In the solver function which I created in the Maze class it uses the self.endpoint to get the endpoint and multiplies it by two because the number given in the text file is a number that only take into count only spots that a star could fit in. The other two methods called are setStar and setExplan which set the space to a star and explation mark.

```
def setStar(self,r,c):
        self.reverselist[r][c] = '*'

def setExplan(self,r,c):
        self.reverselist[r][c] = '!'
```

Comment: How do you know the top right is the exit?

Comment: @EugeneK I used r == (self.endpoint[0]*2) and c == (self.endpoint[1]*2). self.endpoint part of a method that finds the endpoint as it is given in the text document in the 2 line of it.

Comment: We may need to see some more of your code. For example, what does `self.setExplan` do? In general, it is helpful if you can provide enough context that we can *run* your code and see for ourselves exactly what it is doing - see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Although that being said, "it doesn't change the character after finding a dead end" - you call `self.setstar(r, c)` before you start recursing, are you just missing a call to reverse that right before you `return False`?

Comment: @Ivc I have added extra information so I hope you can understand it more. Sorry if it is still confusion I am quite new to recursion and to this website.

Comment: @Ivc Yea, I see that I call `self.setstar(r, c)` before I start recursing, where would I put that line to properly get the maze to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used Python, so haven't run this, but looks to me like you need something like the following in your solver function:

```
if r == (self.endpoint[0]*2) and c == (self.endpoint[1]*2):
    return True
if self.reverselist[r][c] != ' ':
    return False

# mark the current attempt as on the route
self.setStar(r,c)

# don't need to setStar or setExplan anywhere while
# trying moves - the recursive functions will do that
if self.solver(r-1,c):
    return True
if self.solver(r,c+1):
    return True
if self.solver(r,c-1):
    return True 
if self.solver(r+1,c):
    return True

# if we reach here then there is no solution found from
# the current r, c so mark it as ! for backtracking
self.setExplan(r,c)

return False
```

Cheers,

Comment: I'm not sure if it is something wrong with another part of my program but this will just fill the whole maze with exclamation marks. Edit: sorry just checked it with fixed values and it is not detecting the end correctly and it seems to work just need to fix the other part of my function. Thanks for the help.